# How to hide html table particular Sub header when click Main header

Tags: html, angularjs

I have html table by using "data-ng-repeat" filling with the Main header, Sub header. Main header having expand button these headers are getting data from database. I can able to hide td body items but I need to hide particular sub headers columns when I click Main header how can i hide at page load for particular Sub header items how can i take the condition.

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <span>{{mainH}}</span>
                    <span data-ng-click="clickf(first)">+</span>                   
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th data-ng-repeat="SHeader in Subheader">
                    <span>{{SHeader.Subheader}}</span>
                </th> ///this Subheader hide some of the particular sub header items
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="data in items">              

                <td><span>{{data.item0}}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{data.item1}}</span></td>
                <td data-ng-show="show"><span>{{data.item2}}</span></td>
                <td data-ng-show="show"><span>{{data.item2}}</span></td>               
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

Factory.HttpRequest('page.aspx/GetDetails')
            .success(function (data) {
 var Details = data.d;               
                $scope.Subheader= Details.SubDescriptionDetails;
}
```

Comment: How the `Subheader` data looks?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with "Subheader " is entity list items getting from data

Comment: Can you add data example of `Subheader` and `items`

Comment: this is a list kind of data "Subheader[0].subheader1"  `objentity.Subheader = Convert.ToString(dr["SubHeader"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  lstSummary.Add(objentity);`